# Validity check in TASM x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I am trying to do user input validity check in tasm assembly where the user may enter anything and it will only return valid if the user enter number. The problem is even if I enter number the program still return invalid and for second input the console did not do anything it just freeze there.

this is the code

```
.model small
.stack 200h
.data
        prompt_msg1 db "Enter the first number: $"
        prompt_msg2 db "Enter the second number: $"
        valid_input_msg db "valid input$",0
        invalid_msg db "Invalid input, please enter a valid number $",0
        input_buffer db 100 
       
.code

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

GetFirstNumber:
    ; Prompt the user to enter the first number
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset prompt_msg1
    int 21h

    ; Read the input user and store it in a buffer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset input_buffer
    int 21h

    ; Check the validity of the user input
    mov si, offset input_buffer
    call CheckNumber
    cmp al, 0
    je GetFirstNumber

GetSecondNumber:
    ; Prompt the user to enter the second number
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset prompt_msg2
    int 21h

    ; Read the input user and store it in a buffer
    mov ah, 0Ah
    mov dx, offset input_buffer
    int 21h

    ; Check the validity of the user input
    mov si, offset input_buffer
    call CheckNumber
    cmp al, 0
    je GetSecondNumber

valid_input:
    ;Continue with the rest of the program
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset valid_input_msg
    int 21h
    jmp Exit

CheckNumber:
    xor al, al
    mov bl, [si]
    cmp bl, '-'
    je CheckNumberSign
    cmp bl, '0'
    jl InvalidInput
    cmp bl, '9'
    jg InvalidInput
    inc si
    jmp CheckNumberDecimal

CheckNumberSign:
    inc si
    mov bl, [si]
    cmp bl, '0'
    jl InvalidInput
    cmp bl, '9'
    jg InvalidInput
    inc si
    jmp CheckNumberDecimal

CheckNumberDecimal:
    mov bl, [si]
    cmp bl, '.'
    je CheckNumberDecimalPoint
    cmp bl, 0
    je CheckNumberExit
    cmp bl, '0'
    jl InvalidInput
    cmp bl, '9'
    jg InvalidInput
    inc si
    jmp CheckNumberDecimal

CheckNumberDecimalPoint:
    inc si
    mov bl, [si]
    cmp bl, '0'
    jl InvalidInput
    cmp bl, '9'
    jg InvalidInput
    inc si
    jmp CheckNumberDecimal

CheckNumberExit:
    mov al, 1 ;set al=1 if input is valid
    jmp valid_input ;jump to valid section
    ret

InvalidInput:
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset invalid_msg
    int 21h
    ret

Exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

end start
```

Comment: `input_buffer` should receive more than one byte of a buffer to start with. Then, the first byte should be initialised by you to the length of the buffer. The second byte will be written by interrupt 21h service 0Ah to hold the length of the buffer that is in use. The third byte is the first byte of the input actually entered by the user. Furthermore, the input is terminated by a Carriage Return (CR) byte, which has the value 13 (or 0Dh). You're expecting a NUL byte (value 0) and that the user input starts in the first byte of `input_buffer`.

Comment: If your intent was to have 100 bytes for your input buffer, try `input_buffer db 100 dup (0)` which will reserve 100 bytes, all equaling zero. Right now you're reserving one byte with a value of 100. Also in CheckNumberExit you have a `ret` after a `jmp`, which isn't needed since the `ret` will never execute.

Comment: @puppydrum64 `input_buffer db 100 dup (0)` is wrong, because the first byte needs to give the length of the buffer (to be initialised by the caller before calling interrupt 21h service 0Ah).

Comment: Oh, that's right, this is using the string service. My mistake. I think this will work as written actually, since given the programmer's choice of `model` there's a 64k segment reserved for `@data`, so unless there's more `db`s underneath `input_buffer` it's fine. Not the best practice but it will work.

Comment: @puppydrum64 That is also wrong. There is *not* a full 64 KiB reserved if the data section variables add up to only a few dozen bytes as is the case here. You may get lucky and not corrupt anything, eg if the stack follows behind the data section, but it is definitely wrong to assume you have "a 64 KiB segment reserved for `@data`"

Comment: Hmm, well I learned something new today.